# In django-recurrence the between() method with inc=True includes dtstart even when there is no Recurrence then

Tags: django, datetime

This a question on jazzband's [django-recurrence](https://github.com/jazzband/django-recurrence).

I have model with a RecurrenceField:

```
# models.py
class Session(models.Model):
    # other fields
    dates = RecurrenceField(null=True)
```

In the django admin, I add a rule: weekly, Mondays.

I need to get all the Session dates of the current month (including those in the past). However, when I call between() with inc=True, and dtstart = the first day of the month (as decribed in the [docs](https://django-recurrence.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/recurrence_field.html#getting-occurrences-between-two-dates)), then that dtstart is returned too (which is a Tuesday for March 2022):

```
# shell output:
In [7]: obj = Session.objects.all().first()

In [8]: for rule in obj.dates.rrules:
    ...:     print(rule.to_text())
    ...: 
hebdomadaire, chaque lundi  # translates to: weekly, every Monday

In [9]: month_end
Out[9]: datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 31, 0, 0)

In [10]: month_start
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 1, 0, 0)

In [11]: obj.dates.between(month_start,month_end,dtstart=month_start,inc=True,)
Out[11]: 
[datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 1, 0, 0), # this is a Tuesday!
 datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 7, 0, 0), # Monday
 datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 14, 0, 0), # Monday
 datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 21, 0, 0), # Monday
 datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 28, 0, 0)] # Monday

In [12]: obj.dates.between(month_start,month_end,dtstart=month_start,inc=True,)[0].weekday()
Out[12]: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://django-recurrence.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/recurrence_field.html#getting-occurrences-between-two-dates), dtstart is included by default. To exclude it `include_dtstart=False` should be provided as an arg.